# How to stay connected on remote desktop even if different user tries to connect

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm logging through Remote Desktop to windows 7. Some other users sometimes try to connect to the same computer, then a message box pops up with information that I have 30 seconds to block this try or I will be logged off. Sometimes I'm away and then I'm being logged off and when I come back I have to log on again.

Is there a way to turn off this functionality for single user. Is there some application that always breaks this login process ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to remove users/groups from the allowed remote desktop users. This can be populated by groups or individual users. Unfortunately MS did not include a DENY option.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design on Windows 7, and is supposed to force you to buy the costlier Windows Server 2008.

This is a solution : [How to Enable Multiple Concurrent Remote Desktop Connections](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/windows-guides/1879-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-windows-vista-windows-xp-termsrv-dll.html).

Just to remark that by doing this you will probably be violating your Windows EULA.

If you decide to apply this hack, I suggest creating first a system restore point.